# Backing out sales tax

Tags: ms-access

I am creating an access db to track sales from all of my revenue sources (POS, Website, 3rd party website).  All three of them report the final total (sum of products + tax + tips).

I have setup calculated fields in each revenue source table to take the grand total and subtract the tips to generate the sales total.  Where I am getting stuck is how to best approach backing out the sales tax, so my servers don't have to do a bunch of math before entering the data into the database.  I know this is storing de-normalized data, but in the event the tax rate changes, I don't want previous sales records updating incorrectly with the new tax rate.

I know the formulas, and was using two more calculated fields to back out and result with the sale sub total and tax for the sale.  However, this is hard coded into each of the field's expressions for the tables and if/when the tax rate changes poses an inconvenience for updating the tax rate.

I have read online to use VBA, which I don't know and have had difficulty adjusting to my database from examples, and/or use a data macro in the table.  I have tried the macro, but can't seem to figure out how to reference the current tax rate in a separate table for the formulas within the macro.  I have tried using a query, but cannot find a way to update the field in the table from the unbound field on a query form.

Here is an example of the data being stored in each table

- Server ID - Composite Key
- Sales Date - Composite Key
- Number of Tickets - Entered data
- Grand Total - Entered data
- Tip Total - Entered data
- Sales Total - Grand Total - Tip Total
- Sales Amount - Sales Total / 1.08
- Tax Total - Sales Total - Sales Amount

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the Grand Total, Tip Total, and Tax Rate with each entry? Everything else can be calculated when the data is accessed. Since you store the Tax Rate with the entry, it will be the tax rate in effect at that time. If the tax rate changes, any new entries after that will have the new tax rate. When the data are being used you can then calculate/adjust however you want (i.e., with tax rate in effect at time of purchase, if all were with current tax rate, etc., etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...this sparked a different approach that I was initially trying to avoid.  Initially I was trying to reduce the amount of data entry my servers would have to do, and make it easy for me to update the tax rate in just one location inside the database.  With your idea, I can create a look up field in each of the tables related to the sales tax table and set a default value, so it is still in the table, but not have to be selected each time during data entry.  Thanks for the shift in thinking.

Comment: So I finally had a chance to try adding a sales tax lookup field to my table and set the default value to the PK value for the tax rate (only 1).  I entered one record into the table and the formula worked perfectly, but then I closed the table, and updated the tax rate and entered a second record and it updated the first record with the new tax rate.  This is no good..... any suggestions?

Comment: If you store it as a link or index into to the sales tax table then it will be updated. If you just pull the value out of the sales tax table and store the tax rate itself it should not get updated when the lookup table changes.